# Check if selected file using edmodo cropper library is an image or not

Tags: android, image, cropper

While selecting image using the inbuilt CropImageActivity, the picker shows option to select files (of any type) from some external app (WPS Office for my case). So when I select a pdf file (say), onSetImageUriComplete() doesn't cause any error.

```
@Override
    public void onSetImageUriComplete(CropImageView cropImageView, Uri uri, Exception error) {
        progressView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        if (error != null) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Failed to  load image for cropping", error);
            AndroidUtils.showToast("Unable to upload", this);
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Error is not null for such cases. So, nothing shows up in UI and I don't have any way to know if it is an image or not.

I tried checking the extension from URI but in some models (One Plus X for my case), uri doesn't necessarily contain an extension.

I also tried loading the uri into a File and then check using this code:

```
public static boolean isImage(File file) {
        if (file == null || !file.exists()) {
            return false;
        }
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath(), options);
        return options.outWidth != -1 && options.outHeight != -1;
    }
```

But, for One Plus X it again returns false. Is there any other way (which is not resource intensive) to check if the fetched file is an image or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, nothing shows up in UI and I don't have any way to know if it is an image or not.

Call [`getType()` on a `ContentResolver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#getType(android.net.Uri)), passing in the `Uri`. If the MIME type starts with `image/`, it is an image.

Comment: You mean this: `String mimeType = context.getContentResolver().getType(imageUri);`. This returns null for me

Comment: @AvinashGupta: Really? What is the value of the `Uri`?

Comment: file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20170122_162307.jpg

Comment: OK, I thought `getType()` would handle `file` schemes as well as `content` schemes. Use `MimeTypeMap` to get the MIME type.

Comment: If `getType()` works for `content` schemes, then probably I got the solution. Above methods which I mentioned are already working for `file` schemes. Thanks! I'll confirm this for `content`